# Access array parent

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
    String carA= "white";
    String carB= "Blue";
    String[] filter = {carA, carB};

    // This prints me the value, I need the name: carA
    System.out.println(filter[0]);
```

How can I get the name carA instead of it's value given an index of the array.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names in methods are erased in compilation. If you want to keep the names, use a `Map`

```
String carA= "white";
String carB= "Blue";
String[] filter = {carA, carB};
Map m = ...;
m.put("carA", "white");
m.put("carB", "Blue");
```

Comment: Wait so you are creating a map and an array? Why two tho?

Comment: @Victor The array is just from your example. I decided to put my solution after yours